# Hibernate 6 Could not resolve org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations

Tags: hibernate, gradle, hibernate-annotations

Upgraded my Hibernate dependencies from `5.6.11.Final` to `6.1.7.Final`, migrated to the jakarta packages and my project will no longer gradle build because it cannot locate `org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations`.

If I exclude the annotations module from both hibernate dependencies, then I can gradle build, but not debug/compile because it's missing classes found in the annotations module. Adding the module manually at this point brings back the same error.

I'm not sure how to approach this, as the only other related question (also on this site) has no answer and is from a much older version.

Gradle Build Error

```
:api:dev: Could not resolve org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.6.Final.
Required by:
    project :api > org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:6.1.7.Final > org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-hikaricp:6.1.7.Final > org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.1.7.Final

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.0.0' apply true
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '8.0.0-beta2'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

project.sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
project.targetCompatibility = "1.8"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'spongepowered-repo'
        url = 'https://repo.spongepowered.org/maven'
    }
    maven {
        name = 'jitpack-repo'
        url = 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
}

static def loadEnv() {
    def env = [:]

    try {
        def file = new File('.env')
        def scanner = new Scanner(file)
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            def line = scanner.nextLine()
            if (line.contains('=')) {
                def pair = line.split('=')
                env.put(pair[0], pair.length == 2 ? pair[1] : '')
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ignored) { }

    env.putAll(System.getenv())
    return env
}

def env = loadEnv()

shadowJar {
    def remoteGson = 'com.google.code.gson'
    def remoteCommon = 'com.google.common'
    def remoteOpenfeign = 'openfeign'
    def remoteMariaJdbc = 'org.mariadb.jdbc'
    def remoteHibernate = 'org.hibernate'
    def remoteYaml = 'org.yaml.snakeyaml'
    def remoteApacheText = 'org.apache.commons.text'

    def localGson = 'dev.sbs.api.util.google.gson'
    def localCommon = 'dev.sbs.api.util.google.common'
    def localOpenfeign = 'dev.sbs.api.util.openfeign'
    def localMariaJdbc = 'dev.sbs.api.data.sql.mariadb'
    def localHibernate = 'dev.sbs.api.data.sql.hibernate'
    def localYaml = 'dev.sbs.api.data.yaml.snake'
    def localApacheText = 'dev.sbs.api.util.text'

    relocate remoteGson, localGson
    relocate remoteCommon, localCommon
    relocate remoteOpenfeign, localOpenfeign
    relocate remoteMariaJdbc, localMariaJdbc
    relocate remoteHibernate, localHibernate
    relocate remoteYaml, localYaml
    relocate remoteApacheText, localApacheText
}

sourceSets {
    dev {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        }
    }
    devTest {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.dev.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.dev.output
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Deserialization
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.10.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '31.1-jre'
    implementation group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '2.0'

    // Database
    implementation group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '3.1.2'
    implementation group: 'org.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '3.10.6'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-hikaricp', version: '6.1.7.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-jcache', version: '6.1.7.Final'

    // Api Clients
    implementation group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-okhttp', version: '12.2'
    implementation group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-gson', version: '12.2'
    implementation group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '4.3.1'

    // Other
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.10.0'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.4.6'

    // Annotations
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.26'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.26'

    // Tests
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.9.2'
    testRuntimeOnly group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.9.2'
}

configurations {
    devImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    devCompileOnly.extendsFrom compileOnly
    devAnnotationProcessor.extendsFrom annotationProcessor

    devTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    devTestCompileOnly.extendsFrom compileOnly
    devTestAnnotationProcessor.extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    devTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    devTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

// Exclude specific packages while they are being refactored
task devJar(type: Jar, group: 'build') {
    archiveAppendix.value('dev')
    archiveBaseName.value(artifactIdProp)
    archiveVersion.value(versionProp)

    from sourceSets.dev.java
    from sourceSets.dev.output
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'GitHubPackages'
            url = uri('https://maven.pkg.github.com/skyblock-simplified/sbs-api')
            credentials {
                username = env.get('GITHUB_USER')
                password = env.get('GITHUB_TOKEN')
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        devPub(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = groupIdProp
            artifactId = artifactIdProp + '-dev'
            version = versionProp
            artifacts = [devJar]
            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
                configurations.compileOnly.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
                configurations.annotationProcessor.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
            }
        }
        releasePub(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = groupIdProp
            artifactId = artifactIdProp
            version = versionProp
            artifacts = [shadowJar]
            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
                configurations.compileOnly.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
                configurations.annotationProcessor.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:mariadb://' + env.get('DATABASE_HOST') + ':' + env.get('DATABASE_PORT') + '/' + env.get('DATABASE_SCHEMA')
    user = env.get('DATABASE_USER')
    password = env.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.register('devTest', Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.devTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.devTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with my target compatibility of 1.8, Hibernate 6.x only supports Java 11, 17 and 18 (as of this post).

https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/